# How to truncate float values?

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to remove digits from a float to have a fixed number of digits after the dot, like:

```
1.923328437452 → 1.923
```

I need to output as a string to another function, not print.

Also I want to ignore the lost digits, not round them.

Comment: Should -1.233 be truncated to -1.23 or -1.24?

Comment: @Antony *"I want to ignore the lost digits, not round them."*

Comment: @wjandrea So what? He might just as well not considered negative numbers by that moment.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

First, the function, for those who just want some copy-and-paste code:

```
def truncate(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    s = '{}'.format(f)
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        return '{0:.{1}f}'.format(f, n)
    i, p, d = s.partition('.')
    return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])
```

This is valid in Python 2.7 and 3.1+. For older versions, it's not possible to get the same "intelligent rounding" effect (at least, not without a lot of complicated code), but rounding to 12 decimal places before truncation will work much of the time:

```
def truncate(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    s = '%.12f' % f
    i, p, d = s.partition('.')
    return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])
```

## Explanation

The core of the underlying method is to convert the value to a string at full precision and then just chop off everything beyond the desired number of characters. The latter step is easy; it can be done either with string manipulation

```
i, p, d = s.partition('.')
'.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])
```

or the `decimal` module

```
str(Decimal(s).quantize(Decimal((0, (1,), -n)), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
```

The first step, converting to a string, is quite difficult because there are some pairs of floating point literals (i.e. what you write in the source code) which both produce the same binary representation and yet should be truncated differently. For example, consider 0.3 and 0.29999999999999998. If you write `0.3` in a Python program, the compiler encodes it using the IEEE floating-point format into the sequence of bits (assuming a 64-bit float)

```
0011111111010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

This is the closest value to 0.3 that can accurately be represented as an IEEE float. But if you write `0.29999999999999998` in a Python program, the compiler translates it into *exactly the same value*. In one case, you meant it to be truncated (to one digit) as `0.3`, whereas in the other case you meant it to be truncated as `0.2`, but Python can only give one answer. This is a fundamental limitation of Python, or indeed any programming language without lazy evaluation. The truncation function only has access to the binary value stored in the computer's memory, not the string you actually typed into the source code.<sup>1</sup>

If you decode the sequence of bits back into a decimal number, again using the IEEE 64-bit floating-point format, you get

```
0.2999999999999999888977697537484345957637...
```

so a naive implementation would come up with `0.2` even though that's probably not what you want. For more on floating-point representation error, [see the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

It's very rare to be working with a floating-point value that is so close to a round number and yet is *intentionally* not equal to that round number. So when truncating, it probably makes sense to choose the "nicest" decimal representation out of all that could correspond to the value in memory. Python 2.7 and up (but not 3.0) includes a [sophisticated algorithm to do just that](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580), which we can access through the default string formatting operation.

```
'{}'.format(f)
```

The only caveat is that this acts like a `g` format specification, in the sense that it uses exponential notation (`1.23e+4`) if the number is large or small enough. So the method has to catch this case and handle it differently. There are a few cases where using an `f` format specification instead causes a problem, such as trying to truncate `3e-10` to 28 digits of precision (it produces `0.0000000002999999999999999980`), and I'm not yet sure how best to handle those.

If you actually *are* working with `float`s that are very close to round numbers but intentionally not equal to them (like 0.29999999999999998 or 99.959999999999994), this will produce some false positives, i.e. it'll round numbers that you didn't want rounded. In that case the solution is to specify a fixed precision.

```
'{0:.{1}f}'.format(f, sys.float_info.dig + n + 2)
```

The number of digits of precision to use here doesn't really matter, it only needs to be large enough to ensure that any rounding performed in the string conversion doesn't "bump up" the value to its nice decimal representation. I think `sys.float_info.dig + n + 2` may be enough in all cases, but if not that `2` might have to be increased, and it doesn't hurt to do so.

In earlier versions of Python (up to 2.6, or 3.0), the floating point number formatting was a lot more crude, and would regularly produce things like

```
>>> 1.1
1.1000000000000001
```

If this is your situation, if you *do* want to use "nice" decimal representations for truncation, all you can do (as far as I know) is pick some number of digits, less than the full precision representable by a `float`, and round the number to that many digits before truncating it. A typical choice is 12,

```
'%.12f' % f
```

but you can adjust this to suit the numbers you're using.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well... I lied. Technically, you *can* instruct Python to re-parse its own source code and extract the part corresponding to the first argument you pass to the truncation function. If that argument is a floating-point literal, you can just cut it off a certain number of places after the decimal point and return that. However this strategy doesn't work if the argument is a variable, which makes it fairly useless. The following is presented for entertainment value only:

```
def trunc_introspect(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads the float f to n decimal places by looking at the caller's source code'''
    current_frame = None
    caller_frame = None
    s = inspect.stack()
    try:
        current_frame = s[0]
        caller_frame = s[1]
        gen = tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(caller_frame[4][caller_frame[5]].encode('utf-8')).readline)
        for token_type, token_string, _, _, _ in gen:
            if token_type == tokenize.NAME and token_string == current_frame[3]:
                next(gen) # left parenthesis
                token_type, token_string, _, _, _ = next(gen) # float literal
                if token_type == tokenize.NUMBER:
                    try:
                        cut_point = token_string.index('.') + n + 1
                    except ValueError: # no decimal in string
                        return token_string + '.' + '0' * n
                    else:
                        if len(token_string) < cut_point:
                            token_string += '0' * (cut_point - len(token_string))
                        return token_string[:cut_point]
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Unable to find floating-point literal (this probably means you called {} with a variable)'.format(current_frame[3]))
                break
    finally:
        del s, current_frame, caller_frame
```

Generalizing this to handle the case where you pass in a variable seems like a lost cause, since you'd have to trace backwards through the program's execution until you find the floating-point literal which gave the variable its value. If there even is one. Most variables will be initialized from user input or mathematical expressions, in which case the binary representation is all there is.

Comment: How can we apply this function to a dataframe?

Comment: @RohithRNair Off the top of my head, the same way you'd apply any other function that operates on individual elements (i.e. `applymap()`). Maybe there's a way to make the whole operation more efficient, but that would be a matter for a separate question.

Comment: applymap() is taking a lot time since my dataframes are really big. I am trying to compare two dataframes for differences but the floating point precision is skewing my output from the desired. Like you said, I will raise a separate question for the same. Thanks.

Comment: @RohithRNair Ah, well if you're trying to compare two dataframes for differences, ask about that instead. Truncating the values (which is what this question is about) is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Just a note, your code seems to chop negative numbers to negative zero, which can get confusing...

Comment: @Mehrdad I just tested on Python 2.7 and 3.6 and I'm not seeing that. The function works properly for all the negative numbers I tried.

Comment: @DavidZ: What do you get for `truncate(-0.001, 1)`?

Comment: @Mehrdad I get `'-0.0'`, which I believe is the correct result, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidZ: But that's exactly what I was saying... I was saying it gets chopped to negative zero instead of plain zero, which is not what people would normally want I think. It certainly wasn't helpful in my case when I tried to use your code.

Comment: @Mehrdad Oh, I misunderstood, I thought you were saying that all negative numbers regardless of their magnitude get truncated to (some variant of) zero. Anyway, I can see why a person might want to omit the negative sign from the result in some cases, but because floating-point zeros are generally signed, I think a sensible default is to leave the sign there. For comparison, `'{}'.format(-0.0)` produces `'-0.0'`; I'm basically maintaining that behavior. If you want a variant of this that strips the sign when the result is zero, it shouldn't be hard to develop one.

Comment: @DavidZ: Yeah I don't have a problem in my case, just thought I'd leave you a tip for the future poor soul who realizes this "copy-and-paste" code still requires tweaking :P

Answer (score 163):

```
round(1.923328437452, 3)
```

See [Python's documentation on the standard types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex). You'll need to scroll down a bit to get to the round function. Essentially the second number says how many decimal places to round it to.

Comment: I meant rounding isn't what i need. I need truncating, which is different.

Comment: Ahhh, fair enough. My mistake sorry.

Comment: That's a lot of upvotes for an incorrect solution! One of those strange Stackoverflow rarities. I wonder if there's a badge for it...

Comment: It is just appalling how many wrong answers (and upvotes for the wrong answers) there are for this question.

Comment: For those looking for a correct, short and contemporary (2018) answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172324/2965879

Comment: A lot of people will come to this page looking for rounding ;)

Comment: @janjackson and also a lot I people may not particular care whether its rounded of truncated. For example when annotating the points of a graph, it's usually the differences between the points that matters more than the exact decimal values themselves.

Comment: but ```str(round(1.923328437452, 3))``` does work nicely, so I liked this answer.  It allows you to "output a string to another function" as the user asked.

Answer (score 33):

The result of `round` is a float, so watch out (example is from Python 2.6):

```
>>> round(1.923328437452, 3)
1.923
>>> round(1.23456, 3)
1.2350000000000001
```

You will be better off when using a formatted string:

```
>>> "%.3f" % 1.923328437452
'1.923'
>>> "%.3f" % 1.23456
'1.235'
```

Comment: On my Python, that rounds: '%.3f' % 1.23456 == '1.235'

Comment: This is way more elegant than the manual string formatting nonsense, good post!

Comment: `round(1.23456, 3)` is `1.235` and not `1.2350000000000001`

Comment: @Ahmad not necessarily. The example here is from Python 2.6 (note the date of the answer). The string formatting was improved in Python 2.7/3.1, that's probably why you get different results. Nevertheless, floating point numbers will often have unexpected string representations, see: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: This is not correct as the question is about truncating and not rounding.

Comment: Given the specification of the question, the formatting string is actually not bad but needs to be refined: `def trunc_s(x, d): return f"{x:.{d + 1}f}"[:-1]`

Answer (score 29):

```
n = 1.923328437452
str(n)[:4]
```

Comment: Simple and pythonic. 4 is the size of the whole number though, not only the digits after the dot.

Comment: So if the user enters for example `2`, you'll have a decimal dot `.` at the end of the string - not really a good solution I think.

Comment: This is specific to a case to this number. How would it generalise to 11.923328437452?

Comment: Best answer! you also could add float() to return a number: float(str(n)[:4])

Comment: Genius! been searching for half and hour for a smiple solution for numbers but seems the right one is in the strings :))

Comment: Old answer but for future readers, this obviously doesn't work with floats which have more than 1 digit before the decimal point

Answer (score 24):

At my Python 2.7 prompt:

```
>>> int(1.923328437452 * 1000)/1000.0
1.923
```

Comment: I tried the answers above this one but they didn't work and this one did--thank you!

Answer (score 15):

The truely pythonic way of doing it is

```
from decimal import *

with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.rounding = ROUND_DOWN
    print Decimal('1.923328437452').quantize(Decimal('0.001'))
```

or shorter:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D, ROUND_DOWN

D('1.923328437452').quantize(D('0.001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

**Update**

Usually the problem is not in truncating floats itself, but in the improper usage of float numbers *before* rounding.

For example: `int(0.7*3*100)/100 == 2.09`.

If you are *forced* to use floats (say, you're accelerating your code with `numba`), it's better to use cents as "internal representation" of prices: (`70*3 == 210`) and multiply/divide the inputs/outputs.

Comment: Parson me for asking this, but... why?

Comment: @markroxor, not sure what exactly you're asking about. As a sidenote, usually the problem is not with the rounding itself, but with the improper usage of float numbers _before_ rounding. Eg `int(0.7*3*100)/100 == 2.09`. Where did my 1 cent go?

Comment: that makes sense, can you edit your answer with this explanation? thanks.

Comment: Getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'D'`, I believe you wanted to make a named import no ?

Answer (score 14):

Simple python script -

```
n = 1.923328437452
n = float(int(n * 1000))
n /=1000
```

Answer (score 13):

```
def trunc(num, digits):
   sp = str(num).split('.')
   return '.'.join([sp[0], sp[1][:digits]])
```

This should work.  It should give you the truncation you are looking for.

Comment: If the `num` provided is an integer this throws an IndexError due to the missing `.` in the number.

Using partition you could get around this special case. 

`a, dot, b = str(num).partition('.')
return a + dot + b[:digits]`

Answer (score 10):

So many of the answers given for this question are just completely wrong. They either round up floats (rather than truncate) or do not work for all cases.

This is the top Google result when I search for 'Python truncate float', a concept which is really straightforward, and which deserves better answers. I agree with Hatchkins that using the `decimal` module is the pythonic way of doing this, so I give here a function which I think answers the question correctly, and which works as expected for all cases.

As a side-note, fractional values, in general, cannot be represented exactly by binary floating point variables (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary) for a discussion of this), which is why my function returns a string.

```py
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext, ROUND_DOWN

def truncate(number, places):
    if not isinstance(places, int):
        raise ValueError("Decimal places must be an integer.")
    if places < 1:
        raise ValueError("Decimal places must be at least 1.")
    # If you want to truncate to 0 decimal places, just do int(number).

    with localcontext() as context:
        context.rounding = ROUND_DOWN
        exponent = Decimal(str(10 ** - places))
        return Decimal(str(number)).quantize(exponent).to_eng_string()
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think a correct and complete answer would be so hard to find for such a common need... Never seen so many up votes for incorrect answers.

Answer (score 6):

```py
>>> from math import floor
>>> floor((1.23658945) * 10**4) / 10**4
1.2365
```

# *divide and multiply by 10**number of desired digits*

Comment: from math import floor

Answer (score 5):

If you fancy some mathemagic, this works for +ve numbers:

```
>>> v = 1.923328437452
>>> v - v % 1e-3
1.923
```

Comment: As I understand 1e-3 will truncate to 3 digits after dot. I liked this answer but it doesn't seems to work for 4 and 5.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to mention that the old "make round() with floor()" trick of

```
round(f) = floor(f+0.5)
```

can be turned around to make floor() from round()

```
floor(f) = round(f-0.5)
```

Although both these rules break around negative numbers, so using it is less than ideal:

```
def trunc(f, n):
    if f > 0:
        return "%.*f" % (n, (f - 0.5*10**-n))
    elif f == 0:
        return "%.*f" % (n, f)
    elif f < 0:
        return "%.*f" % (n, (f + 0.5*10**-n))
```

Answer (score 4):

I did something like this:

```
from math import trunc


def truncate(number, decimals=0):
    if decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError('truncate received an invalid value of decimals ({})'.format(decimals))
    elif decimals == 0:
        return trunc(number)
    else:
        factor = float(10**decimals)
        return trunc(number*factor)/factor
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n
```

testing:

```
>>> f=1.923328437452
>>> [truncate(f, n) for n in range(5)]
[1.0, 1.9, 1.92, 1.923, 1.9233]
```

Comment: This only truncates with positive numbers, negative numbers will round down (away from zero).

Answer (score 2):

A general and simple function to use:

```
def truncate_float(number, length):
    """Truncate float numbers, up to the number specified
    in length that must be an integer"""

    number = number * pow(10, length)
    number = int(number)
    number = float(number)
    number /= pow(10, length)
    return number
```

Comment: Great! The cast to int truncates both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
def precision(value, precision):
    """
    param: value: takes a float
    param: precision: int, number of decimal places
    returns a float
    """
    x = 10.0**precision
    num = int(value * x)/ x
    return num
precision(1.923328437452, 3)
```

> > 1.923

Comment: Nice but you are not rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Short and easy variant

```
def truncate_float(value, digits_after_point=2):
    pow_10 = 10 ** digits_after_point
    return (float(int(value * pow_10))) / pow_10

>>> truncate_float(1.14333, 2)
>>> 1.14

>>> truncate_float(1.14777, 2)
>>> 1.14


>>> truncate_float(1.14777, 4)
>>> 1.1477
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a pandas df this worked for me

```
import math
def truncate(number, digits) -> float:
    stepper = 10.0 ** digits
    return math.trunc(stepper * number) / stepper

df['trunc'] = df['float_val'].apply(lambda x: truncate(x,1))
df['trunc']=df['trunc'].map('{:.1f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def trunc(f,n):
  return ('%.16f' % f)[:(n-16)]
```

Answer (score 1):

int(16.5);
this will give an integer value of 16, i.e. trunc, won't be able to specify decimals, but guess you can do that by

```
import math;

def trunc(invalue, digits):
    return int(invalue*math.pow(10,digits))/math.pow(10,digits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way:

```
def truncate(num, res=3):
    return (floor(num*pow(10, res)+0.5))/pow(10, res)
```

for num = 1.923328437452, this outputs 1.923

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy workaround in python 3. Where to cut I defined with an help variable decPlace to make it easy to adapt.

```
f = 1.12345
decPlace= 4
f_cut = int(f * 10**decPlace) /10**decPlace
```

Output:

```
f = 1.1234
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The core idea given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784665/10645311) seems to me to be the best approach for this problem.
Unfortunately, it has received less votes while the [later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176526/10645311) that has more votes is not complete (as observed in the comments). Hopefully, the implementation below provides a short ***and*** complete solution for ***truncation***.

```
def trunc(num, digits):
    l = str(float(num)).split('.')
    digits = min(len(l[1]), digits)
    return l[0] + '.' + l[1][:digits]
```

which should take care of all corner cases found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176526/10645311) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784665/10645311).

Answer (score 1):

Most answers are way too complicated in my opinion, how about this?

```
digits = 2  # Specify how many digits you want

fnum = '122.485221'
truncated_float = float(fnum[:fnum.find('.') + digits + 1])

>>> 122.48
```

Simply scanning for the index of '.' and truncate as desired (no rounding).
Convert string to float as final step.

Or in your case if you get a float as input and want a string as output:

```
fnum = str(122.485221)  # convert float to string first
truncated_float = fnum[:fnum.find('.') + digits + 1]  # string output
```

Comment: Your proposal is problematic if the number being truncating is small since you would waste a lot precision with the leading 0 to the right of the decimal point. But this problem is endemic to the problem as stated. What I'm trying to say is that significant figures is the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better version would be just to find the `index` of decimal point `.` and then to take the string slice accordingly:

```py
def truncate(number, n_digits:int=1)->float:
    '''
    :param number: real number ℝ
    :param n_digits: Maximum number of digits after the decimal point after truncation
    :return: truncated floating point number with at least one digit after decimal point
    '''
    decimalIndex = str(number).find('.')
    if decimalIndex == -1:
        return float(number)
    else:
        return float(str(number)[:decimalIndex+n_digits+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int(1.923328437452 * 1000) / 1000
>>> 1.923

int(1.9239 * 1000) / 1000
>>> 1.923
```

By multiplying the number by 1000 (10 ^ 3 for 3 digits) we shift the decimal point 3 places to the right and get `1923.3284374520001`. When we convert that to an int the fractional part `3284374520001` will be discarded. Then we undo the shifting of the decimal point again by dividing by 1000 which returns `1.923`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
n = 1.923328437452
float(str(n)[:5])
```

NOTE [:5] is not inclusive. Prints float

```
1.923
```

Alternatively, the following will give you the same result and it is more efficient. If you need two decimal for example just change 1000 to 100:

```
int(n * 1000) / 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use numpy.round

```
import numpy as np
precision = 3
floats = [1.123123123, 2.321321321321]
new_float = np.round(floats, precision)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple enough to fit in a list-comprehension, with no libraries or other external dependencies. For Python >=3.6, it's very simple to write with f-strings.

The idea is to let the string-conversion do the rounding *to one more place than you need* and then chop off the last digit.

```
>>> nout = 3  # desired number of digits in output
>>> [f'{x:.{nout+1}f}'[:-1] for x in [2/3, 4/5, 8/9, 9/8, 5/4, 3/2]]
['0.666', '0.800', '0.888', '1.125', '1.250', '1.500']
```

Of course, there *is* rounding happening here (namely for the fourth digit), but rounding *at some point* is unvoidable. In case the transition between truncation and rounding is relevant, here's a slightly better example:

```
>>> nacc = 6  # desired accuracy (maximum 15!)
>>> nout = 3  # desired number of digits in output
>>> [f'{x:.{nacc}f}'[:-(nacc-nout)] for x in [2.9999, 2.99999, 2.999999, 2.9999999]]
>>> ['2.999', '2.999', '2.999', '3.000']
```

Bonus: removing zeros on the right

```
>>> nout = 3  # desired number of digits in output
>>> [f'{x:.{nout+1}f}'[:-1].rstrip('0') for x in [2/3, 4/5, 8/9, 9/8, 5/4, 3/2]]
['0.666', '0.8', '0.888', '1.125', '1.25', '1.5']
```

Answer (score -1):

Am also a python newbie and after making use of some bits and pieces here, I offer my two cents

```
print str(int(time.time()))+str(datetime.now().microsecond)[:3]
```

str(int(time.time())) will take the time epoch as int and convert it to string and join with...
str(datetime.now().microsecond)[:3] which returns the microseconds only, convert to string and truncate to first 3 chars

Answer (score -1):

```
# value  value to be truncated
# n  number of values after decimal

value = 0.999782
n = 3
float(int(value*1en))*1e-n
```

Answer (score -3):

If you mean when printing, then the following should work:

```
print '%.3f' % number
```

Comment: That rounds the number off, it doesn't truncate.