# Convert to Float without Rounding Decimal Places

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I have a list and it contains a certain number `'5.74536541'` in it which I convert to a float.

I am printing it out in Python 3 using `("%0.2f" % (variable))` but it always prints out 5.75 instead of 5.74.

I know you're thinking who cares, but it is for a currency converter program and I don't want the currencies to round up/down but to be exact.

How can I keep it from rounding but also keep the 2 decimal places?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Comment: If you are certain that the string is a number, then you can just process the text directly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, 5.75 is closer to the number than 5.74.  Keep the numbers stored as floats, and let them print with rounding - what's the problem?

Comment: @wim: Didn't he mention the reason in the question? `I know you're thinking who cares, but it is for a currency converter program and I don't want the currencies to round up/down but to be exact.`

Comment: @wim When I use Google's currency converter it converts to 5.74 not 5.75, I am using that to be exact.

Comment: That is not 'exact' though.  The proper way to do it is have all the maths in full precision (possibly even using decimal module, for financial stuff) and only round for printing purposes.

Comment: I don't think "exact" means what you think it means

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't use floating point numbers for currency, due to rounding errors like you mentioned.

Your best bet is to use a [fixed-precision `decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) where you also have full control over how rounding and truncation works. From the docs:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext()
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999999, Emax=999999999,
    capitals=1, flags=[], traps=[Overflow, DivisionByZero,
    InvalidOperation])

>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal('3.0')
Decimal('3.0')
>>> Decimal('3.1415926535')
Decimal('3.1415926535')
>>> Decimal('3.1415926535') + Decimal('2.7182818285')
Decimal('5.85987')
>>> getcontext().rounding = ROUND_UP
>>> Decimal('3.1415926535') + Decimal('2.7182818285')
Decimal('5.85988')
```

You should represent all currency-based values internally as `Decimals` with a high precision (the standard level of precision should be fine in your case - just leave the `prec` alone!). If you want to print a nicely formatted dollars and cents value to the user, using the `locale` module is a straightforward way to do this.

Be careful when printing as you will have to quantize the `Decimal` down to the correct number of places for display or the rounding will not be based on your `Decimal` context! You should only perform the `quantize` step for final display or for a single, final value - all intermediate steps should use high-precision `Decimal`s to make any operations as accurate as possible.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_AU.UTF-8'
>>> getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN
>>> TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2
>>> var = Decimal('5.74536541')
Decimal('5.74536541')
>>> var.quantize(TWOPLACES)
Decimal('5.74')
>>> locale.currency(var.quantize(TWOPLACES))
'$5.74'
```

Comment: I'm doing getcontext().prec = 2, then var = Decimal('5.74536541') but it just prints out 5.74536541?

Comment: When you create a new `Decimal` object, it is created with the precision required to represent that object (see in the example above where Pi is input with more than 6 significant figures after setting the context). Doing an operation on that decimal should return a new decimal object with the context's precision (e.g. `var - 0`). Are you sure you want such low precision? I think you might want to keep precision as high as required and `ROUND_DOWN` for final 2-digit display? Also, prec = 2 should yield `5.7` for your example.

Comment: That's odd, the docs say >>> getcontext().prec = 6 >>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7) returns >>> Decimal('0.142857'), but I tried that and it isnt working for me. Does prec = 2 mean that it keeps 2 decimal places or am I thinking of something else? And unfortunately yes I need it to 2 decimal places, because $5.74 exists but $5.745 is not a real currency value.

Comment: The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations. Note that precision controls significant figures, not necessarily decimal places. Try with some bigger numbers to test that out!

Comment: To summarise, you should do all of your calculations with `Decimal` objects and with a high level of precision. For printing dollars and cents values, consider using `locale`. I'll update my answer with an example of this.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow got it to work by just using the Decimal mod.

Comment: It is a little bit complicated, but then, you want to have calculations that are accurate, round down/truncate your result in a specific way, and print the output. When dealing with currency, it's always important that accuracy comes first. What if you rounded incorrectly for thousands of transactions? [Salami Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing), ala Office Space, or Superman III.

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with currency and accuracy matters, don't use `float`, use `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values are known as "useful approximations". Whatever you do to a floating point number—round it, truncate it, whatever—if the result is a floating point value, *you* don't get to decide how many digits to the right of the decimal point it has.

*Never* use floating point values for currency. See `pydoc decimal`, for example. Python's decimal module supports decimal fixed point and decimal floating point arithmetic.

Python docs [warn about rounding floats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round).

> Note The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
>   is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
>   can’t be represented exactly as a float.

If you're not careful, you'll be [misled by the value that appears at the interpreter prompt](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

> Python only prints a decimal approximation to the true decimal value
>   of the binary approximation stored by the machine.

And

> It’s important to realize that this is, in a real sense, an illusion:
>   the value in the machine is not exactly 1/10, you’re simply rounding
>   the display of the true machine value. This fact becomes apparent as
>   soon as you try to do arithmetic with these values

Answer (score 1):

Take away the number mod 0.01

i.e.

```
rounded = number - (number % 0.01)
```

then print it the same as before.

This said, rounding down is **not** more accurate. Are you trying the old steal money from a bank by exploiting rounding errors scheme?

Comment: `This said, rounding down is not more accurate.` Bank will not give you more when you convert currency, though. It's a legitimate reason to truncate.

Comment: It will take `0.01` even from `$2,000.00` which is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

If the number is a string then truncate the string to only 2 characters after the decimal and then convert it to a float. 
Otherwise multiply it with 10^n where n is the number of digits after the decimal and then divide your float by 10^n.