# Python - Flooring floats

Tags: python, math, floor

This is a really simple question. Lets denote the following:

```
>>> x = 1.2876
```

Now, `round` has this great optional second parameter that will round at that decimal place:

```
>>> round(x,3)
1.288
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to round down the numbers. `math.floor(x,3)` returns an error rather than `1.287`

Comment: By "rounding down" do you mean toward 0 or toward negative infinity?  It makes a difference for negative numbers (like `floor(-3.1) == -4.0`).

Comment: By the way, that's just how round behaves, since .876 is closer to .88 than .87 Why would you want it to floor?

Comment: Interesting question though.

Comment: Sounds like you want to truncate, answers to this question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't really make sense due to errors in representation of floating point numbers. You could have a result that is close to 1.287 and mathematically your "floor" should be 1.287 (say), but   instead you get 1.286 due to errors between what the real result should be vs it's floating point representation

Comment: @NathanJhaveri I don't think it's related, technically, flooring and truncating is a bit different.

Comment: @gnibbler yes I do understand that, but it's not because of floating points all the times. rounding up could get me out of the boundaries where rounding down can never do that

Comment: Why not use `x = min(x, upperboundy)` then?

Comment: I am using x in mathematical operations. This is for flexible operations so the actual bound is irrelevant at this state, I just cannot risk the number being larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just something that appeared in my mind. Why don't we convert it to string, and then floor it?

```
import math
def floor_float(x, index):
    sx = str(x)
    sx = sx[:index]+str(math.floor(float(sx[index]+"."+sx[index+1])))
    return float(sx)
```

A little advantage is that it's more representating-error-proof, it's more accurate in representating the numbers (since it's a string):

```
>>> floor_float(10.8976540981, 8)
10.897654
```

This maybe not the best pythonic solution though.. But it works quite well :)

**Update**

In Python 2.x, `math.floor` returns a float instead of integer. To make this work you'll to convert the result, to an integer:

```
    sx = sx[:index]+str(int(math.floor(float(sx[index]+"."+sx[index+1]))))
```

**Update2**

To be honest, the code above is basically nonsense,  and too complicated ;)

Since it's flooring, you can just truncate the string, and float it back:

```
def floor_float(x, i):
    return float(str(x)[:i])
```

Comment: yes this avoids issues with floating points!! I'm not going to use this solution, because I will want the number to represent simply after the decimal, but I think I will go with this technique

Comment: @aIKid, did you edit this code? It doesn't work as shown now; e.g., `floor_float(10.8976540981, 8)` raises `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10.897654.0` on the `return` stmt.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x? I just noticed that it also doesn't work there. Hang on.

Comment: @aIKid, Python version doesn't matter - the code that's currently shown is obviously nonsense ;-)

Comment: :) i know that. Basically you can just truncate the string. That's why i upvoted yours. I didn't upvote mine :)

Answer (score 3):

This may be the easiest, if by "rounding down" you mean "toward minus infinity" (as `floor()` does):

```
>>> x = 1.2876
>>> x - x % .001
1.287
>>> x = -1.1111
>>> x - x % .001
-1.112
```

This is prone to lots of shallow surprises, though, due to that most decimal values cannot be exactly represented as binary floating-point values.  If those bother you, do something similar with `decimal.Decimal` values instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's always `floor(x*10**3)*10**-3`.

Comment: Note: it's numerically better to divide by 10**3 instead.  One rounding error instead of two (10**-3 suffers its own rounding error, and then multiplying by that contributes another rounding error).  And it's faster to do floor(x*1e3)/1e3 ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters confirmed. if x has five decimal places, `math.floor(x*10**5)*10**-5` results in
`1.2876500000000002`

Comment: @aIKid, that's the kind of "shallow surprise" I was referring to in my own answer.  It's impossible for _any_ method to avoid those in all cases - binary floats only approximate decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

```
def roundDown(num, places):
    return int(num*(10**places))/float(10**places)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, building on the `decimal` module's more elaborate facilities.  Like the builtin `round()`, this also supports negative "digits":

```
>>> round(1234.5, -1) # builtin behavior for negative `ndigits`
1230.0
>>> round(1234.5, -2)
1200.0
>>> round(1234.5, -3)
1000.0
```

and you can use any of the 8(!) rounding modes defined in `decimal`.

```
from decimal import ROUND_DOWN
def rfloat(x, ndigits=0, rounding=ROUND_DOWN):
    from decimal import Decimal as D
    proto = D("1e%d" % -ndigits)
    return float(D(str(x)).quantize(proto, rounding))
```

Example:

```
for i in range(-4, 6):
    print i, "->", rfloat(-55555.55555, i)
```

produces:

```
-4 -> -50000.0
-3 -> -55000.0
-2 -> -55500.0
-1 -> -55550.0
0 -> -55555.0
1 -> -55555.5
2 -> -55555.55
3 -> -55555.555
4 -> -55555.5555
5 -> -55555.55555
```

Try to parse strings instead at your own risk ;-)