# Python String Formatting, string library

Tags: python

how to print out no more than two decimal digits of accuracy like 5.32 instead of 5.32436675? Is there any keyword regarding this in python.

Comment: I recommend getting to know the [Python String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) section of the Python docs. Lots of great stuff in there.

Comment: By the way, do you want to round or just truncate?

Comment: As Christian said, Python String Formatting is very useful. If you want to round, however, python string formatting will give you problems. My answer is about rounding, that that's what you want to do. His answer is about string formatting, if that's what you want to do-- Go with whichever one applies.

Comment: @Christian As evidenced by his using *accuracy*, I think he might have wanted rounding?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
a = 5.32436675
print("%.2f" % a)
```

Remember this is rounding.

If you just want to truncate use this method from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python)

```
def trunc(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    slen = len('%.*f' % (n, f))
    return str(f)[:slen]

print(trunc(a, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to round to 2 places, as seen below:

```
round(number, 2)
```

Example:

```
round(5.32436675, 2)
```

Output:

```
5.32
```

This is preferable to float implementations (truncating solutions) because the rounding means the number is still mostly accurate. You don't want `5.319` to get cut off to `5.31` when it should be `5.32`!

Happy coding!

Comment: Fails for `round(5.32536675, 2) --> 5.33`.
`

Comment: @hcwhsa No... that's what it's supposed to do. That's what rounding is.

Comment: But I don't think OP wants this output.

Comment: @hcwhsa OP wants "two decimal places of **accuracy**". Truncating is not accurate, it's truncating. Rounding is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
n = 23.232323
print "%.2f" % n
```

The '.2' here indicates 2 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks Fraser, for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

According to [string format specifications](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) :

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(5.32436675)
5.32
```

Answer (score 0):

% formatting is getting a bit old.  The new way:

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(5/9))
```