# Reduce the decimal points in Python

Tags: python-2.7, rounding

I have an array `array([0.79836512, 0.79700273,  0.82697546,  0.82016349,  0.79087192], dtype=float32)`

and I want to keep the first two decimal points without round.
So, I need an array like that,

`array([0.79, 0.79,  0.82,  0.82,  0.79], dtype=float32)`.

Is it possible to do this with `python`?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncating floats in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python)

Comment: This question has many duplicates than required. Please use Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach for truncating to two decimals is to truncate `x * 100` and divide that by 100, which works for numpy arrays:

```
>>> np.trunc(a * 100) / 100
array([ 0.79000002,  0.79000002,  0.81999999,  0.81999999,  0.79000002], dtype=float32)
```

Don't be put off by the trailing non-zero digits in the output, those are just an artifact of floating-point imprecision:

```
>>> np.float32(.79)
0.79000002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and re-use it later:

```
import numpy as np
x= np.random.random(5)
x=np.array(x, dtype=np.float16)
print(x)

formatting = lambda x: "%.2f" %x

x_2dp=[]

for i in x:
    x_2dp.append(formatting(i))
    print(x_2dp)
```

but the answer is a string which you can convert to float.