# Change number of numbers after dot

Tags: python, decimal

I wrote a simple python script that counts the time it takes to send a HTTP request using urllib2.

After i count the the time, it prints the number of time. It looks like this:
2.582848693

I dont really need all the decimal numbers, I only need 1 decimal number. I need it would be :
2.5

How can it be done using Python? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use string formatting as follows:

```
print "%.1f" % total_time
```

.1f means that the parameter should be printed as a float with 1 decimal

Or you can write this to print it with 2 decimals and some extra text:

```
print "The total amount of time is %.2f" % total_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
x = 2.582848693
y = int(x*10)/10.0
```

`y` contains a copy of `x` value with just one decimal digit and you can print it as well as use it.

You could also just print `int(x*10)/10.0`.