# Is there a way to inhibit rounding in python?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

is there a way to inhibit python rounding, e.g.:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 11; print (Decimal(1.1237836550999999999)*10**10)
11237836551
```

I need to show the first 10 decimal places of the decimal number, so actually I need `11237836550` as output and I do not need that rounding on the last digit (in this case that 0 rounded to a 1).

Sometimes I can just increase the precision (not in this case) and then perform the calculation safely, like this:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 14; print (Decimal(1.12378365509978)*10**10)
11237836550.998
```

But suppose that you are not aware of the decimal part of the number after that '0', e.g. it could be 1.1237836550999999999999999999999999... and so on, and then you cannot rely upon this 'workaround'.

So, is there a way to tell python, "for this calculation, I don't want any rounding to be performed, actually I want that you just return me the needed number of decimals (10 in this example), and throw away anything else after it"?

I took a look here [Truncating floats in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python), but basically what I need is not a string of a truncated float, but another decimal to use to perform calculations upon.
Furthermore, the `trunc` function of the accepted answer in the post I linked will not work in this case, cause the Decimal will be rounded just before it will be passed to the function's 'f' argument:

```
>>> def trunc(f, n):
...     '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
...     return ('%.*f' % (n + 1, f))[:-1]
... 
>>> trunc(Decimal(1.12378365509978), 10)
'1.1237836551' # and not 1.1237836550 as needed
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are finding:

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 103

def precision(context, prec=100):

    return Decimal(context).quantize(Decimal('.'+'0'*(prec-1)+'1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)

print precision(Decimal(10).log10() / Decimal(2).log10())
```

Output:

```
3.3219280948873623478703194294893901758648313930245806120547563958159347766086252158501397433593701550
```

Comment: This seems a more reliable solution, doesn't it?

Comment: How can I use quantize with a variable result, i.e. the result of an expression, `Decimal(math.sqrt(2) + 5).quantize('.00000000001')` gives a `TypeError: conversion from str to Decimal is not supported`

Comment: @user3019105 Inside `quantize` is `Decimal`, don't forget it! `In[5]: Decimal(math.sqrt(2) + 5).quantize(Decimal('.00000000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)` will give your output without Error

`Out[5]: Decimal('6.41421356237')`

Comment: How can I use `.quantize()` with an expression like: `Decimal(Decimal(2).sqrt() + Decimal(5)).quantize(Decimal('.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001'))` which outputs `Decimal('6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785697')` but the expected output would be `Decimal('6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696')` i.e. the last decimal place has a 6 and not 7?

Comment: You need to specify the rounding method, as shown in the answer: `(Decimal(2).sqrt() + Decimal(5)).quantize(Decimal('.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)`

Comment: @user3019105 In my computer, I cannot get so many number after `.` like your. It only give me 27 digit, so I cannot test your case. But as @mata said, don't forget `rounding=ROUND_DOWN`, it should do the job. I edited my answer so that you don't have to trouble your eyes with dozens of `0` in `quantize`

Comment: @mat, @dragonfly, with ROUND_DOWN quantize works fine for the sqrt of 2 + 5, but I have also tested it with this expression: `getcontext().prec = 101; (Decimal(Decimal(10).log10() / Decimal(2).log10())).quantize(Decimal('.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)`, which is the logarithm base 2 of 10 with its first `100` decimal places.  Even with ROUND_DOWN it outputs...(continue in the comment below)

Comment: it outputs `Decimal('3.3219280948873623478703194294893901758648313930245806120547563958159347766086252158501397433593701551')` while the exact output is... `Decimal('3.3219280948873623478703194294893901758648313930245806120547563958159347766086252158501397433593701550')`, as the 100th decimal of log(10)/log(2) is `0`, what should be done in such a case?

Comment: @user3019105 You should give `getcontext().prec` a number that a little bit higher than the precision that you want, (eg. `103`)  then it should work.

Comment: @dragon2fly Yeah, increasing the precision works, but is it reliable even if e.g. the number had an infinite series of *9s* after that '0'? I know it looks maniacal, but I need as much as possible a universal solution, can I rely upon setting the precision just a little bit higher and be sure that the number will be that one and not a rounded one even if the decimal part after it has a series of infinite 9s? Does ROUND_DOWN help here?

Comment: @user3019105  set `getcontext().prec = 200`, try to put `prec=100` and then `prec=110` with your expression above. With `prec=110` it gives you `...55099...` and with `prec=100` it gives `...550` . So I think it would be reliable regardless of how many and what digits after the `pre`th digit are

Answer (score 7):

You problem is not `Decimal`. It's `float`. Namely:

```
>>> 1.1237836550999999999
1.1237836551
```

But if you do:

```
>>> int(Decimal("1.1237836550999999999")*10**10)
11237836550
```

You are good to go. Use strings when initializing decimals with higher precision.

Comment: Good, thank you, does it works always, even if I have a number with infinite 9s? like 1.1237836550999999999999999999.........?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for `>>> getcontext().prec = 11; print (int(Decimal(1.123783655099999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)*10**10))` it still outputs `1.1237836551`

Comment: @user3019105 you are still missing the quotes. Use a string. If you write it as you have, it's converted to the machine-precision floating point number before passing to the Decimal constructor; double precision floats have around ~15 decimal places of precision, so all the 9's you wrote down are just useless.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Now it works, but what is the purpose of the int() here, it seems to work even without it: `print (Decimal('1.12378365509999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999')*10**10)`
outputs 11237836550

Comment: @user3019105 Note that I'm using the python shell in my examples. If you want to use this in a script which prints to the standard output, you will need `print`

Comment: It works, what about the int()? What's it's purpose?

Comment: `print Decimal("1.1237836550999999999")*10**10` outputs, 
11237836550.99999999900000000. Using `int` you will strip the non-integer part.

Comment: All right, thank you for you help, just the last question, how can I make it work while having an expression? I can do e.g.: `>>> getcontext().prec = 41; print (Decimal( str( Decimal(2).sqrt() + Decimal(5) )))` which outputs `6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785697` but I need to output `6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696`, just to know how can I use this tricks with an expression with variables?

Comment: @user3019105 `getcontext().prec = 41 + 1; print str(Decimal( str( Decimal(2).sqrt() + Decimal(5) )))[:-1]` seems to do the trick

Comment: It works with 41 + 1, but not for 40 + 1, i.e. for the first 39 decimal places to be right, `getcontext().prec = 40 + 1; print (str(Decimal( str( Decimal(2).sqrt() + Decimal(5) ))))` outputs `6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785697` while the correct one would be `6.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696`, is there a way in such a case?