# Python string format a float, how to truncate instead of rounding

Tags: python, string.format

Is there a format option such that

```
>>> '%.1(format)'%2.85
```

gives '2.8'?

In Python 2.7, 'f' format rounds to nearest

```
>>> "{:.0f}".format(2.85)
'3'
>>> "%.0f"%2.85
'3'
>>> "%.1f"%2.85
'2.9'
>>> "%i"%2.85
'2'
```

Comment: x=Decimal('2.85');
`format(x,'0.1f')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for a complete list of supported floating point format specifiers.

You need to [round in your code instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python)