# Python 3.5.0 decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

So I need to cut off some decimals cases in my output.

I have the following line:

```
print ("O valor a pagar é de ", ***float(n3)*1.3***, " euros.")
```

In the area that I highlited I get to much cases... The output is something like this for example: `2,47893698236923` and I want it to show only 2 decimal cases like: `2,47`.

How do I do it? And I'm using python 3.5.0

Comment: @OP : caution, output is with decimal *point* no *coma* (except if you work with the locale standard module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by BlivetWidget, floating format causes rounding not truncating.

You can use the Decimal module :

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

x = 2.47893698236923
print(Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
print(Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal('.001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
```

output :

```
2.47
2.478
```

EDIT 
As the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial) explains :

> The quantize() method rounds a number to a fixed exponent. This method
>   is useful for monetary applications that often round results to a
>   fixed number of places

EDIT 2

See also [Truncating floats in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python)

Comment: That did not work in my python module...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Pictures\Ines\python\exerciocio 1.py", line 36, in <module>
    print ("O valor a pagar é de ", Decimal(str(float(n3)*1.3).quatize('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN), " euros.")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'quatize'

Comment: @Ines: You misspelled `quantize`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `round()` function.

```
print("O valor a pagar é de ", round(float(n3) * 1.3, 2), " euros.")
```

Comment: that helped. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Based on the example you gave, you want to truncate a value (the other answers at this time will round the value).  If you just want to truncate, I would use a string slice.

```
>>> num = 2.47893698236923
>>> str(num)[:str(num).find('.') + 3]
'2.47'
```

PS: if you don't know if there will be a decimal in there, you could use this variant:

```
>>> numstr = str(num)
>>> numstr[:(numstr.find('.') + 3) if numstr.find('.') else None]
'2.47'
```

Comment: Can whoever is downvoting this answer explain why the answer is not useful, especially considering that it's the only answer that gives the output requested by the OP?

Comment: I didn't downvote your post. But, the Op is not requering rounding because rounding 2.47893698236923 -> 2.48. EDIT you are right, .2f is rounding instead of pruning, I was not aware of this.

Comment: @P.Ortiz That's my point, all of the other answers round the value (try one or two of them), while I truncated the value as requested.  (PS rounding 2.47893698236923 to two decimal places is actually 2.48)