# Select a part of a float value and randomize the missing part in Python

Tags: python, random

If i have a float number like `float = 51.31876543`.

How can I create a new float value selecting the first seven numbers and generating randomly the remain numbers? To obtain something like this:

```
float = 51.31876 + 3 random numbers
like 51.31876411 or 51.31876739 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert your float number to a string and then add your 3 random numbers.
first, let's see how you can make your random numbers: by using `random` library. I suggest `random.randint()`.

```
import random
f = 51.31876543

# now you must choose the first seven numbers that you have in mind.
f_str = str(f)[:8]

# we assume that your number is always a float.
# if you were not sure if it is an integer or a float, you can code this:
if '.' not in f_str:
    f_str.pop()

# now make your random 3 number and add it to your number:
f_str = f_str + str(random.randint(100, 999))

f = float(f_str) # change type from string to float.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the truncate function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python) to get just the 5 decimal values, multiply it by 100.000, sum with a random int between 100 and 999, divide it by 100.000 and the rounding up to 5 decimal values again.

```
def truncate(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    s = '{}'.format(f)
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        return '{0:.{1}f}'.format(f, n)
    i, p, d = s.partition('.')
    return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])

import random
float = 51.31876543
float = truncate(float, 5)
float = float * 10e5
random_3_numbers = random.randint(100,999)
float += random_3_numbers
float /= 10e5
float = truncate(float, 5)
```

Also, your question is badly tagged. It should contain `python` and other tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `random.randint()`:

```
from random import randint

f = 51.31876543
f = str(f)[:8]
if '.' not in f:
    f.pop()
for _ in range(3):
    f += str(randint(0,9))
print(f)
```

Output:

```
51.31876308
```