# How to Turn off scientific notations in values in Pyspark?

Tags: azure, pyspark, types, databricks, azure-databricks

I have dataframe having one decimal column (23,8). In pyspark dataframe some value is 0 but it is being displayed as 0E-8. Due to this we are having issue after conversion to csv.

How to turn off scientific notation? I don't want 0E-8. It should be 0.00000000.
Can anyone help me on this?

Tried casting. But not working.

Comment: yes Dileep, I am using Azure Databricks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68994392/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-digits-after-decimal-point-in-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the below function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import format_number
```

You can apply the function to your decimal column to format it as a string with the desired number of decimal places

In this example, we use the format_number function to format the decimal column with 8 decimal places and create a new column called "formatted_column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import format_number
data = [(0.00000000,), (123.45678901,), (9876.54321098,)]
columns = ["decimal_column"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)df = df.withColumn("formatted_column", format_number("decimal_column", 8))
df.show()
```

[image]

- Format the decimal column with 8 decimal places

This should prevent the scientific notation (e.g., 0E-8) and display the decimal values with 8 decimal places (e.g., 0.00000000) in the CSV output.

Comment: Thanks Dileep it has helped. Now no scientific notations using this method. Is there any spark settings that these notation can be turned off?

Comment: Hi dileep, this solution is adding commas in the values..this is again prob for us