# Why do two numpy arrays not compare equal if they print the same?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, gaussian, inverse

I've a piece of code to find the inverse of a matrix using Gaussian elimination.
To check if the solution is correct, I match it with the numpy linalg.inv solution. They appear to be same, but it returns false when I check. This is what I mean

```
e = inverse(zeze)
```

```
[[ 0.11111111  0.37037037 -0.2962963 ]
 [ 0.88888889 -0.03703704 -0.37037037]
 [-0.22222222 -0.07407407  0.25925926]]
```

And this is the other one

```
d = np.linalg.inv(zeze)
print(d)
```

```
[[ 0.11111111  0.37037037 -0.2962963 ]
 [ 0.88888889 -0.03703704 -0.37037037]
 [-0.22222222 -0.07407407  0.25925926]]
```

```
print(d== e)
```

```
[[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
```

The matrix zeze is

```
zeze = np.array([[1,2,4],[4,1,6],[2,2,9]])
```

And the code snippet for the inverse function is

```
def copier(a):
    row = len(a)
    col = len(a[0])

    copi = np.zeros((row,col))
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            copi[i][j] = a[i][j]
    return copi
def inverse(a):
    if len(a) == len(a[0]):
        detm = np.linalg.det(a)
        if detm == 0:
            print("If the determinant of a matrix equals zero, it's impossible to find it's inverse.")
            print("And guess what Sherlock? ")
            print("This one has a determinant zero")
        elif detm != 0:
            
            mat_copy = copier(a)
            id_mat = np.identity(len(a))
            id_mat_copy = copier(id_mat)
            rows_mat = list(range(len(a)))

            for diag in range(len(a)):
                scaler = 1.0/mat_copy[diag][diag]
                for i in range(len(a)):
                    mat_copy[diag][i] *= scaler
                    id_mat_copy[diag][i] *= scaler
                for j in rows_mat[0:diag] + rows_mat[diag+1:]:
                    crScaler = mat_copy[j][diag]
                    for k in range(len(a)):
                        mat_copy[j][k] = mat_copy[j][k] - crScaler * mat_copy[diag][k]
                        id_mat_copy[j][k] = id_mat_copy[j][k] - crScaler * id_mat_copy[diag][k]
        print(id_mat_copy)
    else:
        print(len(a))
        print(len(a[0]))
        print("First of all, you're stupid enough to try to invert a non-square matrix")
        print("Secondly, if you were not sure, why didn't you check the invertibility first?")
        print("Overconfident kids these days")
```

Comment: Most probably because you are comparing floating point values. .. 0.111111111111111112 != 0.111111111111111111  - and only 0.11111111 are shown.

Comment: The obvious thing to do here would be to print the difference between the two arrays, to see the exact magnitude of the difference.  It's probably going to be something on the order of 1e-15; expecting exact equality of floats is unreasonable.  This is exactly why numpy has an `.allclose()` method.

Comment: Try to compare the first elements manually and see the outcome. If they are not, try truncating them using *round()* or *floor()*. I'm no expert, but I can't help noticing that you are using floating point numbers that can sometimes be bitches. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/how-to-truncate-float-values

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing floating point values. Only some of the actual digits are shown - and `0.11111111111111111111` is not the same as `0.11111111111111111112`

Use [numpy.allclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to compare them.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.11111111, 0.37037037, -0.2962963],
              [ 0.88888889, -0.03703704, -0.37037037],
              [ -0.22222222, -0.07407407, 0.2592592600000]])

b = np.array([[0.11111111, 0.37037037, -0.2962963],
              [ 0.88888889, -0.03703704, -0.37037037],
              [ -0.22222222, -0.07407407, 0.2592592600001]])

print(a == b)

print(np.allclose(a,b))  # accepts delta for comparison, see documentation
```

Output:

```
# a == b
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True False]]

# allclose
True
```