# How to truncate (round down) an f-string float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to truncate (round down) my f-string formatted float. My original float variable with value `700.75` becomes `700.8` after using f-string with a precision of 1. For ex., I use f-string as below.

```py
quantity = float(f'{quantity:.1f}')
```

My desired value is `700.7` with precision one. How can I achieve that while still using f-strings?

Comment: Watch out - that kind of rounding is trickier than you might think, because floats are binary, not decimal. For example, the float normally displayed as `0.3` actually has value `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, and if you try to display that to 1 digit after the decimal point, rounded down, you'll see `0.2`, not `0.3`.

Comment: Take a look at the second answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/how-to-truncate-float-values

Comment: Why do you need to use f-strings for this? Does `math.floor(quantity * 100) / 100` not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to truncate float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/how-to-truncate-float-values)