# I have a value like 68.82809999... And I'd like to take only the 2 decimals after the dot in python

Tags: python, math

Since I'm working with values like the one mentioned in the title, and I am currently using python, how could I take the 2 decimals after the dot? Preferably using no libraries.

I'm expecting to input a value like 68.82809999... and get a value like 68.82 back.

Comment: `round(68.82809999, 2)  68.83`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Comment: If you want `68.828...` to give `68.82` rather than `68.83` that's called truncation rather than rounding.

Comment: (Specifically, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/783927/765091. Some of the answers to that question do rounding, not truncation.)

Answer (score 0):

I think, links in comment sections answered your question, However, this is one of the approach:

```
def truncate_decimals(number):
  # Convert the number to a string
  number_str = str(number)

  # Split the string at the decimal point
  integer_part, decimal_part = number_str.split('.')

  # Take the first two characters after the decimal point
  truncated_decimal = decimal_part[:2]

  # Concatenate the integer part and truncated decimal part
  result = f"{integer_part}.{truncated_decimal}"

  return float(result)

# Example usage
original_value = 68.82809999
truncated_value = truncate_decimals(original_value)

print(truncated_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had found answers about my question but they were all using external libraries.

Comment: That's a lot of code for `from math import trunc; trunc(num * 10**2) / 10**2` =)

Answer (score -3):

maybe you should create a function with at first reads the `math.floor()`
of a number and then reads the next 3chars and just joins those things together and returns it. Unfortunate for you, you would have to `import math` to the python project.